# codeigniter File not found issue with function in URI

Tags: codeigniter

I will try to explain my problem as simple as possible.

My **index URI is working as well** and displays my "test" message.

```
https :// domain.com /
```

But **other URIs doesn't work** and displays "File not found" message.

```
https :// domain.com / about
```

Whereas, this URI is working like i want :

```
https :// domain.com / index.php / about
```

I really don't understand why, can someone help me ? thanks for your help ! :)

my route

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^pages/view(/)?(.*)$ /$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^pages(/)?(.*)$ /$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^((user_guide|img|css|js|scripts|fonts)\/.*|index\.php|assets/|robots\.txt|.*\.css)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

my controller file name

```
Pages.php
```

my controller class

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        echo'test';
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

my config uri protocol (i've already tried with QUERY_STRING and PATH_INFO)

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I would be really happy to get your help !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try using the following in .htaccess and check.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Welcome Galex! Glad that helped you.